# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'AuthenticateEventArgs' is less accessible than method 'AuthenticateEventArgs'

Tags: sql, asp.net

Getting following error

> Error: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'WebForm1.AuthenticateEventArgs' is less accessible than method
>   'WebForm1.LoginControl_Authenticate(object,
>   WebForm1.AuthenticateEventArgs)'

Code is:

```
protected void LoginControl_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error arises because the definition of *AuthenticateEventArgs* contains an accessibility more restrictive than the *protected* accessibility of the method that uses it. You should have an accessibility *protected* or *public* in the definition of the *WebForm1.AuthenticateEventArgs*.